Why is this shader stretching the overlay?
I have the following shader where I expect to write an overlay onto a video frame, but the result is an overlaid image which is stretched horizontally by a factor 2. What could be causing this issue? If I comment either writing to videoY or videoUV I can see that both stretch the overlay equally.
The overlay texture is 1920x1080 and set to bgra8Unorm. It is created from a pixel buffer with pixel format kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA. The Y texture is 1920x1080 and set to r16Unorm and the UV texture is 960x540 and set to rg16Unorm, both coming from a single pixel buffer with the pixel format kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange.
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
kernel void overlayShader(texture2d<half, access::read_write> videoY [[ texture(0) ]],
                          texture2d<half, access::read_write> videoUV [[ texture(1) ]],
                          texture2d<half, access::read> overlay [[ texture(2) ]],
                          uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    if (gid.x >= videoY.get_width() || gid.y >= videoY.get_height()) return;
    
    half4 bgra = overlay.read(gid);
    if (bgra.a == 0.0) return;
    
    half3 rgb = half3(bgra.r, bgra.g, bgra.b);
    
    // Conversion Matrix from RGB to YUV (BT.2020, Limited Range)
    half3x3 rgbToYuv2020Limited = half3x3(
                                          0.2627,  0.6780,  0.0593,
                                          -0.13963, -0.36037,  0.500,
                                          0.500, -0.45979, -0.04021
                                          );
        
    half3 yuv = rgb * rgbToYuv2020Limited;
    
    // Adjust for subsampled UV plane
    uint2 uvCoord = uint2(gid.x / 2, gid.y / 2);
    
    videoY.write(yuv.r, gid);
    videoUV.write(half4(yuv.g, yuv.b, 0.0, 0.0), uvCoord);
}

Note that the shader is incomplete with respect to color management. I will add alpha blending later and verify color conversions. My issue right now is with the extent of the overlay.

Edit, after the suggestion by @Spo1ler I did a GPU capture and I can see the issue. The Y and UV components consist of two squeezed similar looking images side-by-side, each occupying half the size of the image. The overlay comes in looking like a normal image. When the shader writes the overlay onto Y and UV it appears on both the left and right side, but not squeezed. The result is that it becomes stretched. I am not sure how to deal with this situation though.
Screenshot of the GPU capture showing the overlay to the left and the Y component upper right and UV component lower right.

Edit, This may be coincidental, but stereoscopic video is sometimes stored as side-by-side in a single frame (left eye | right eye). Could I inadvertently have enabled something like that?

You can do a GPU capture and see what the shader is actually doing.

Thank you, the GPU capture gives a good hint at why this is happening, but I don't know how to resolve the issue. See updated question above with the results of the capture.

I'm gonna need to see how you are creating those textures

Look at the function addOverlayToVideo here: https://github.com/Roenbaeck/tubeist

May be coincidental, but stereoscopic video sometimes use frames like the ones I see.

It finds zero results in your repo by addOverlayToVideo

I decided to use a CIContext and CIRenderDestination with a CIBlendKernel in the meantime, so the function is gone in the latest commit. Here's a link to the exact function as it looked: https://github.com/Roenbaeck/tubeist/blob/c4902b5222a236cda4862536c40ea5988fcc401d/Tubeist/OneBigFile.swift#L866
